# Add TomCat to XAMPP installation

Tags: windows-10, xampp, tomcat

Months ago I've instelled XAMPP to my windows 10 computer with only:

- Apache
- MySQL

but now, I need install TOMCAT.

Actually I have 3 projects on my `htdocs` froder, what would be the best way to add `TOMCAT` to my XAMPP.

I tried with xampp installer, but it wants to override php instalation, for another new one.

[image]

What would be the best way to add TOMCAT to my existing XAMPP without having to reinstall or re-download my actual php projects?

Answer (score 2):

If you are worried about your PHP folder, you can:

- Stop Apache.
- Navigate to your XAMPP installation folder.
- Copy the `php` folder in place (so you get another folder called e.g. `php - Copy`.
- Install Tomcat with the XAMPP installer.
- Making sure Apache is still stopped, go back to your XAMPP installation folder.
- Delete your `php` folder and rename `php - Copy` back to `php`.

Answer (score 2):

You can install [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) separately from XAMPP.
Just remember that Tomcat needs a prior installation of Java.

After the installation of Tomcat, modify its file `server.xml`
(located in folder `tomcat_installation_path\conf` )
to change the default port number
to another number than 8080, because 8080 is used by XAMPP.

Example: Change `Connector port="8080"` to `Connector port="8081"`.

Now when you start XAMPP you go to `localhost:8080`,
and whenever you run Tomcat you go to  `localhost:8081`.

You may also do it in other way round as well, keeping the default port number of
Tomcat and changing  XAMPP's port number.

References:

- [Configure and Use Apache Tomcat](http://www.sintesisdigital.com.mx/dashboard/docs/configure-use-tomcat.html)
- [How to change Tomcat default port ?](http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-change-tomcat-default-port/)

Comment: Not possible with existing installation of xampp?

Comment: Possible, with side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to do it. Bitnami is a program of the same creators of XAMPP (and it is almost the same as XAMPP), and includes Tomcat

[Bitnami Changelog](http://changelog.), [Bitnami Tomcat Readme](https://bitnami.com/stack/tomcat/README.txt), [Bitmani Tomcat Download](https://bitnami.com/stack/tomcat/installer)